# Laravel Mutiple Image Saving Always lacks 1 image

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, image-uploading, laravel-blade

I've been looking at mycode for an hour now, and I just cant really find whats wrong with my codes. When I upoload 3 images it only saves 2 when 4 its 3 and so on and etc, so here is my code:

Controller

```
if(Input::hasFile('images'))
    {

    $file = Input::file('images');

    foreach($file as $files) {
        $img = Image::make($files)->resize(300, 240);
        $lgimg = Image::make($files);
    $name = time().'-'.'chicken.jpg';


    $img->save('images/chickens/thumbs/'.$name,30);

    $lgimg->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $lgimg->save('images/chickens/'.$name,60);

    $newimage = new Photo;
    $newimage->chicken_id=$idinsert;
    $newimage->photo_loc=$name;
    $newimage->save();

    }

    }
```

Views

```
    {{ Form::label('tuimg','Upload Image')}}
    {{ Form::file('images[]', array('multiple'=>true)) }}
```

Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the Problem, it is the filename that is not changing that's why the photos always lacks, its using the same filename, because i am using the time. To explain it further here is the code

if(Input::hasFile('images'))
        {

```
    $file = Input::file('images');

    //we need to a changing value on every save
    $myarray=0;

    foreach($file as $files) {
        $img = Image::make($files)->resize(300, 240);
        $lgimg = Image::make($files);
    $name = time().'-'.$myarray.'chicken.jpg';

    $img->save('images/chickens/thumbs/'.$name,30);

    $lgimg->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    $lgimg->save('images/chickens/'.$name,60);

    $newimage = new Photo;
    $newimage->chicken_id=$idinsert;
    $newimage->photo_loc=$name;
    $newimage->save();

    $myarray++;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Instead of time and incrementing a variable you can use datetime function date("Y-m-d H:i:s") like this.